# How to get field value in Java reflection

Tags: java, reflection, java-8

I have following field in a class:

```
private String str = "xyz";
```

How do I get the value `xyz` using the field name *only* i.e.

I know the name of the field is `str` and then get the assigned value. Something like:

```
this.getClass().getDeclaredField("str").getValue();
```

Currently the Reflection API has `field.get(object)`.

Comment: if you are doing that just for fun, go ahead, but using reflection *usually* implies (unless you work on a library) some XY problem

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use:

```
String value = (String) this.getClass().getDeclaredField("str").get(this);
```

Or in a more generalized and safer form:

```
Field field = anObject.getClass().getDeclaredField(fieldName);
field.setAccessible(true);
String value = (String) field.get(anObject);
```

And for your example, this should be enough:

```
String value = this.str;
```

But you probably know of that one.

**Note:** `anObject.getClass().getDeclaredField()` is potentially unsafe as `anObject.getClass()` will return the actual class of `anObject`. See this example:

```
Object anObject = "Some string";
Class<?> clazz = anObject.getClass();
System.out.println(clazz);
```

Will print:

```
class java.lang.String
```

And not:

```
class java.lang.Object
```

So for your code's safety (and to avoid nasty errors when your code grows), you should use the actual class of the object you're trying to extract the field from:

```
Field field = YourObject.class.getDeclaredField(fieldName);
```

Comment: You should not use `getClass()` together with `getDeclaredField`, as this will break when there are subclasses. Use a class literal of the `NameOfTheActualClass.class` form.

Answer (score 0):

Imagine you have object in variable `foo`.

Then you need to get `Field`

```
Field field = foo.getClass().getDeclaredField("str");
```

then allow access to private field by:

```
field.setAccessible(true);
```

and you can have value by:

```
Object value = field.get(foo);
```

Comment: exactly the answer already posted... :|

Comment: @Eugene it was edited.